# Button does not appear to be clickable

Tags: html, button, submit

I grabbed a login page template to implement into my site and created a register page based on the login page template.  I am having problem with the actual button click.  When i hover over the button it changes colors but the mouse pointer does not switch the the finger when you hover over a link/button.  When i click the button nothing happens.  I have a php file set up to check the fields and then submit the information into a database.  Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Register</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/login_register.css">

</head>

<body>

  <html lang="en-US">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Register</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
     <![endif]-->

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <div id="login">

        <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="post" action="register.php" autocomplete="on">

          <fieldset class="clearfix">

            <p><span class="fontawesome-user"></span>
              <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" value="First Name" onBlur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'First Name'" onFocus="if(this.value == 'First Name') this.value = ''" required>
            </p>
            <!-- JS because of IE support; better: placeholder="Username" -->

            <p><span class="fontawesome-user"></span>
              <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text" value="Last Name" onBlur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'Last Name'" onFocus="if(this.value == 'Last Name') this.value = ''" required>
            </p>

            <p><span class="fontawesome-envelope"></span>
              <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="Email" onBlur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'Email'" onFocus="if(this.value == 'Email') this.value = ''" required>
            </p>

            <p><span class="fontawesome-user"></span>
              <input id="username" name="username" type="text" value="Username" onBlur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'Username'" onFocus="if(this.value == 'Username') this.value = ''" required>
            </p>

            <p><span class="fontawesome-lock"></span>
              <input id="password" name="password" type="password" value="Password" onBlur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'Password'" onFocus="if(this.value == 'Password') this.value = ''" required>
            </p>

            <p><span class="fontawesome-lock"></span>
              <input id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" type="password" value="Password" onBlur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'Password'" onFocus="if(this.value == 'Password') this.value = ''" required>
            </p>

            <!-- JS because of IE support; better: placeholder="Password" -->

            <p>
              <input type="submit" value="Register">
            </p>

          </fieldset>

        </form>

      </div>
      <!-- end login -->

    </div>

  </body>

  </html>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: two action attribute in the form `<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="post" action="register.php" autocomplete="on">`

Comment: try `<form method="post" action="register.php" autocomplete="on">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<form method="post" action="register.php" autocomplete="on">
```

Error is two action attribute in the form `<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="post" action="register.php" autocomplete="on">`

Answer (score 0):

I have rewrite coding. you can use them. I have removed multiple **action**. I uses placeholder instead **value="Username" onBlur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'Username'" onFocus="if(this.value == 'Username') this.value = ''"**. Also we must not use **value="First name"**. Now you have already written all values. It will affect form validation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Register

```
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Register</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
```

```
<div class="container">

  <div id="login">

    <form method="post" action="register.php" autocomplete="on">

      <fieldset class="clearfix">

        <p><span class="fontawesome-user"></span>
          <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" required />
        </p>
        <!-- JS because of IE support; better: placeholder="Username" -->

        <p><span class="fontawesome-user"></span>
          <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required />
        </p>

        <p><span class="fontawesome-envelope"></span>
          <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" required />
        </p>

        <p><span class="fontawesome-user"></span>
          <input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" required />
        </p>

        <p><span class="fontawesome-lock"></span>
          <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required />
        </p>

        <p><span class="fontawesome-lock"></span>
          <input id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" type="password"  placeholder="Confirm Password" required />
        </p>

        <!-- JS because of IE support; better: placeholder="Password" -->

        <p>
          <input type="submit" value="Register" />
        </p>

      </fieldset>

    </form>

  </div>
  <!-- end login -->

</div>
```